# Selecting value on condition when doing groupby using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my sample `df` looks like this:

```
sid    score   completed
101      70      NaN
102      56      Yes
101      65      No
103      88      Yes  
103      50      NaN  
102      42      No  
105      79      NaN  
....
```

**What do I want?**

- I want to groupby `sid` and take the `max score` from the `score` column.
- For the `completed` column, I want to take the value `Yes` if the `groupby` "group" column contains `Yes` else choose `No` or simply `NaN` if it does both "Yes" or "No" does not exists

My final `df` should look like this:

```
sid    score_max   completed
101       70           No
102       56           Yes
103       88           Yes  
105       79           NaN  
....
```

**What did I do?**

```
df_groupby = df.groupby(['sid']).agg(
    score_max = ('score','max'),
    completed = ('completed', any(completed="Yes"))
)
```

However, the solution does not work. Could you please assist me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use ordered `pd.CategoricalDtype` to solve your problem:

```
>>> df.astype({'completed': pd.CategoricalDtype(['No', 'Yes'], ordered=True)}) \
      .groupby('sid') \
      .agg(score_max=('score', 'max'), completed=('completed', 'max')) \
      .reset_index()

   sid  score_max completed
0  101         70        No
1  102         56       Yes
2  103         88       Yes
3  105         79       NaN
```

Detail about category:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['No', 'Yes', np.NaN]})
df1['Col1'] = df1['Col1'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(['No', 'Yes'], 
                                                     ordered=True))
```

```
>>> df1['Col1'].min()
'No'

>>> df1['Col1'].max()
'Yes'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to work on the solution. Quick clarification: does .astype() get executed first or .groupby()? ... the solution takes a very long time to compute. do you suggest doing `df.astype({'completed': pd.CategoricalDtype(['No', 'Yes'], ordered=True)})` first?

Comment: The dtype category is set before groupby. How many records do you have in your real case and how much time does it take to execute?

Comment: My `df` has around 1.2m rows. If the `dtype` category is set before groupby is done then can I first execute `df.astype({'completed': pd.CategoricalDtype(['No', 'Yes'], ordered=True)})` and then just do `df.groupby(...)` ?

Comment: another question @Corralien why was the category limited to `['No', 'Yes']` what if there is `NaN`?

Comment: In this case, use the second form as `df['completed'] = df['completed'].astype(...)`. Each value that is not in the category is set to `NaN`.

Comment: thank you @Corralien! is this the correct code and clarification? `(ques #1)` : `df['completed'] = df['completed'].astype({'completed': pd.CategoricalDtype(['No', 'Yes'], ordered=True)})`?  `(ques #2)` : if `['No', 'Yes']` does not exist on the row value then it will be set to `NaN`?  `(ques #3)` : I have other columns where I need to perform same thing, so I repeat the same step? `(ques #4)` : once all is done then I can start the `groupby` and filter using `max` for `Yes` and `min` for `No`?